# Show more comments button has broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, user-interface

When clicking Show More Comments, the browser window gets pulled down to the active comment. I wonder if this is just a temporary bug everyone's aware of or it's worth mentioning. Maybe others have a problem with it too?

(I'm using Firefox)

[image: GIF image of Show More Comments effect]

Comment: I don't like this feature very much. I always have to scroll back up to see the comments the "more" comments are replying to.

Comment: @Andre451 But it's helpful in posts like these: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/3933332 to see which comments got expanded.

Comment: @Rizier123 Hmm... maybe.  The same thing happens when you leave a comment as well though (it jumps to your comment), so it doesn't seem right...

Comment: To be fixed soon: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269833/please-fix-jarring-new-page-jump-when-posting-comments

Comment: @MarcGravell Yep, this was the first comment expansion to not suffer from it :) (edit: and this the first comment not to as well!)  I'm also pretty sure I didn't refresh this page before expanding your comment, I'm now wondering what JS trickery you guys are managing to pull to deliver the update without a refresh...

Comment: @Rizier123 I think if you wanted to accomplish that, just slightly changing the background color on said comments would be the way to go.

Comment: @user193661 actually that is part of the work we've been doing; we just need to figure out what color we want to use on each of however many sites each with different UI themes ;p It is already coded to support that, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was actually a specific design choice; however, I'm seeing considerable pushback, so I'll disable it for now while we discuss it further. Should be fixed in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for rolling that back. Is there a question where this is being discussed?

Comment: @CubeJockey the intent was to take you to the first of the new comments; nothing more exciting than that